# Move some videos between firebase storage and youtube

Tags: node.js, firebase, youtube, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I keep videos on FS Storage. I'd like to move some videos to Youtube using FS Functions and Youtube API and node.js. I use Service Accounts to connect the Google servers.
When I take file from bucket and put to body, FS logs show nothing. Why script doesn't insert video to youtube? Is there another way to move files between Google storage and Youtube?
My code

```js
const vfile = bucket.file('/videos/test.MOV');

youtube.videos.insert({
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title: "Testing YoutTube API NodeJS module"
                  , description: "Test video upload via YouTube API"
                }
              , status: {
                    privacyStatus: "private"
                }
            }
          , part: "snippet,status"
          , media: {
                body: vfile.createReadStream()
            }
        }, (err, data) => {
            console.log("DONEinsert.",data);
   console.log("ERRORinsert.",err)
            process.exit();
        });
```

Comment: Nobody doesn't know how transfer videos from Google Cloud to Youtube?

Comment: did you find a solution @Alisher?